# R: modify variables defined in function

Tags: r, list, function, scope

I have a long list of variables which I'm using a function to wrap them into a list. The output list will be then passed to another function.

for example,

```
 #var1:var10
 foo <- function(){
 var1 = 1
 var2 = 3
 var3 = var1 + var3
 var4 = var3*var2 
 #e.t.c
 return(unlist(as.list(environment())))
 }
 params <- foo()
 foo_solve(model,params)
```

Is there a way to access the variables defined inside foo and modify/overwrite the default values then have the `foo` re-evaluated and gets passed to `foo_solve`?

I've tried this approach :

```
  foo <- function(..., args = list()) {  
  defaults <- list(a = -1,  c = -3, d = -4)  
  Args <- Reduce(modifyList, list(defaults, args, list(...)))
  return(unlist(Args))
   }
```

but what about the variables that are calculated based on other ones?

`list(a = value, c = value2, d = a + d)` doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, that you've correctly identified using functions for your solution, but completely overstepped. But let's take the questions one-by-one:

> Is there a way to access the variables defined inside foo?

No, this is by design that what's defined in a function stays within the function, and is only accessible from the function and its children (i.e., whatever the function itself is calling).

> Is there a way to ... modify/overwrite the default values?

This is what function arguments are for, as you correctly deduced. But the solution is simpler; first, for the input variables:

```
foo <- function(var1 = 1, var2 = 3) {
  var3 <- var1 + var2
  var4 <- var3 * var2
  return(c(var1, var2, var3, var4))
}
```

Note: Your return statement is very difficult to read, and potentially dangerous if you need, say, a 5th intermediate variable. It, too, will be returned, and you cannot guarantee the order of the returned variables.

If you need named variables, use a named vector:

```
  return(c(v1=var1, s2=var2, var3=var3, m4=var4))
```

If your returned values are more complex than some scalar values, just use `list` instead of the simple `c`.

> but what about the variables that are calculated based on other ones?

This is where it gets fun; there are several options depending on the complexity of what you want to do and how much flexibility the user should have. First, we can try to extend the above solution to include the computed values and only calculate them if not given:

```
foo <- function(var1 = 1, var2 = 3, var3, var4) {
  if (missing(var3))
    var3 <- var1 + var2
  if (missing(var4))
    var4 <- var3 * var2
  return(c(var1, var2, var3, var4))
}
```

The function `missing` simply tells you, if the argument `var3` was provided. R is a bit funny here as in other languages, function arguments without defaults must be given when calling the function. R doesn't play like that and will only require the variable if you ask for it.

But, if `var3` and `var4` are simple calculations, couldn't they just be defined in the function signature?

```
  foo <- function(var1 = 1, var2 = 3, var3 = var1 + var2, var4 = var3 * var2) {
    return(c(var1, var2, var3, var4))
  }
```

Turns out it works in this case ***but don't do it!***. It will not work for more complex data types (lists, data frames) and it is bad coding style, because it also makes the function less readable.